# Regular expression in TypeScript: find 12 consecutive digits in a string

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to use regex in Typescript to get a 12 digit ID out of a string, the ID has to be 12 consecutive digits. For example:

1. cnsk:bwjn{}vrjn123456789012:nrjgi => 123456789012
2. 42326hbjsbrdjg:hdbj||nj:123456789012vnesu66 => 123456789012

What regex pattern should I use?
How can I integrate it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general JavaScript regex solution which might work here:

```js
var myString = "42326hbjsbrdjg:hdbj||nj:123456789012vnesu66";
var arr = myString.match(/(?:^|\D)(\d{12})(?:$|\D)/);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

This finds a 12 digit number, surrounded on both sides by either non digit characters, or the start/end of the input.

Comment: Interesting pattern. Kudos.

Comment: @Bren The pattern I really wanted to use is: `(?=\D)\d{12}(?=\D)`, however not all versions of JS support lookbehinds like this.